# Are Apple headset volume control buttons not compatible with Android phones?

Tags: hardware

I have recently transitioned from the iOS ecosystem to the Android ecosystem, and I just realised that although my iOS headsets can be used to pause and play the tracks and receive calls, their volume control buttons do not work, while the stock headset from the Samsung phone has working volume control buttons.

The only source I can find for this is [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11350174/2236349), which states that Android cannot ever achieve compatibility due to Apple's patents. However, it does not cite a source.

Can anyone confirm that this is indeed the case with a reputable source?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this a while ago and they didn't work for me either. So no, Apple stuff won't work on Android phones.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a fly-by-night shot, but,  has anybody try Tasker at all? One should be able to set up the media controls for Tasker to pick up the buttons pushed on the headset/ear buds and forward them to the media control for the current media player, in theory at least. This would only work if the hardware even registers the volume button presses.

If I get the time I'll see about snagging a pair with volume and answer buttons to test it out and I'll come back here if it works to post the steps to make it work. My two cents, enjoy.